# How to enter Immersive Reader on Microsoft Edge through Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver, immersive-reader

On a high level, does anyone know how to enter the Immersive Reader mode on Microsoft Edge when it is available for a given webpage through Selenium?

My aim is to load up a page, enter Immersive Reader, and save the page's source code to disk. I'm firing up Edge through Docker and I'm pragmatically connecting to it via a Node.js script.

I've tried driver.actions().sendKeys(KEY.F9), but that doesn't work since I'm targeting the browser and not a DOM element.

Many thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### New

Just run

```
driver.get('read://' + url)
```

and the site is loaded in immersive reader mode if available.

### Old

To interact with the UI you have to use pyautogui (`pip install pyautogui`) and then run this code while the browser window is on focus/active:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.press('F9')
```

It is also useful for example to save a pdf by interacting with the popup window appearing when pressing CTRL+S.

Comment: Interesting. I'll give it a try, but I'm not sure it will scale well given browser resolution becomes important for this technique. I'd ideally like to be able to run this headless in the future.

Comment: @G-R it seems like it is enough to do `driver.get('read://' + url)`

Comment: It isn't working for me; when you do this then print to PDF the page is blank

Comment: Nevermind it is working! note that this ONLY works in `--headless` mode (probably because I believe printtoPDF only works in headless mode)

Comment: @ColtonCampbell are you talking about `driver.get('read://' + url)`? to me it works in non headless mode

Comment: @ColtonCampbell That's interesting because I can only driver.get('read://' + url) in headful mode. It doesn't work in headless for me!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of code for anyone else who might stumble across this:

Credits to [@sound wave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8157304/sound-wave) for [helping me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75160522/7568648) get there!

```js
const { Builder } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const fs = require('fs');

(async () => {

    const driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('MicrosoftEdge').usingServer('http://localhost:4444').build();

    await driver.get('read://https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/entertainment-arts-64302120'); // this URL needs to be Immersive Reader supported

    await driver.switchTo().frame(0);
    const pagesource = await driver.getPageSource();

    fs.writeFile('test.html', pagesource, err => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });

    const title = (await driver.getTitle()).trim();
    console.log(title);

    await driver.quit();

})().catch((e) => console.error(e));
```